# Syntax error while trying to download selenium using pip on python 3.8.2

Tags: python, selenium, pip

I got this error:

```
File "main.py", line 2
    python38 -m pip install selenium
                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

It comes up when I try to run my code. I am using python on [replit](http://replit.com) and have already imported pip on a previous line. Can anyone give me suggestions on what is wrong here?

Comment: That's a command for your OS command line, *not* something to put in a Python script.  I doubt that this is something you can do on repl.it anyway, you'd need the code to be running locally so that it can control a browser also running on your machine.

Answer (score 1):

I used selenium on [replit](http://replit.com) a few months ago and it does work, but it's not the smoothest experience (especially when you have a free tier).

**Installing selenium on [replit](http://replit.com):**

1. You can install it by running `python -m pip install selenium` in
   shell (next to console)
2. Make **requirements.txt** file, paste all required modules there and use this code with [`os.system` method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/how-to-execute-a-program-or-call-a-system-command) (which you can use to execute commands):

```py
import os
os.system("python -m pip install -r requirements.txt")
```

3. When you import selenium at the beginning in [replit](http://replit.com) it should automatically download it, but if it doesn't then:

```py
os.system("python -m pip install selenium")
```